# php include file also include the style of this file

Tags: php, html, css

i have a PHP codes in index.php like this:

```
<?php
$modal = @$_GET["mod"];
switch ($modal){
    default:
    include "blank.php";
    break;

    case "video":
    include "video.php";
    break;
}
?>
```

In my video.php i have some text:

```
<p> Welcome, this is video page </p>
```

When i am clicking:

```
<a href=index.php?mod=video> This is nice video </a>
```

I am getting the message "Welcome this is video page" until here everything is working...

The problem is when i am putting the paragraph inside in div, my paragraph is hiding...

```
<div style="z-index:3;position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;background-color:black;>
    <p> Welcome, this is video page </p>
</div>
```

The question is: How to activate this div style ? I want to see this div style.

Comment: missing a " at end of style in your div tag...

Comment: what's the status of this question? answers provided but no interaction on your part or accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error code demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEDC5PF8198I)

**Error:** You missed `"` in `style`

**Replace this to:**

```
<div style="z-index:3;position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;background-color:black;>
    <p> Welcome, this is video page </p>
</div>
```

**This:**

```
<div style="z-index:3;position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;background-color:black;">
   <p> Welcome, this is video page </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `"` after `background-color:black;`:

```
<div style="z-index:3;position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;background-color:black;">
    <p> Welcome, this is video page </p>
</div>
```

But the default will be black on a black background so be sure to change the text color.

Also as noticed by @JustOnUnderMillions :

```
<?php
$modal = @$_GET["mod"];
switch ($modal){

    case "video":
    include "video.php";
    break;

    default:
    include "blank.php";
    break;
}
?>
```

`default` should always be the last element of your switch.

Comment: `default` doesn't need to be last, it just needs a `break` if it isn't last. The PHP is valid, if it weren't the OP wouldn't get the `Welcome this is video page`.

Comment: @chris85 I run into the same brain bug. Good Pratice _should_ place the `default` at the bottom, it is not a MUST, but more readable, also `default` is the last option in a switch, so place it at last. ;-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Why do you say `default is the last option in a switch`? It can be first, second, etc. Yes it is clearer as the last rule, but not mandatory. First also might be cleaner depending on the set up of the switch.

Comment: @chris85 `default is the last option in a switch` when no `case` hits the income. I mean in the  processflow not in the written code:-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Oh, ha, yea, the definition of default, not the position.